# How to create dynamic javascript object from c# dictionary

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a data structures as follows:

```
public class Entity
{
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }

}

 public class MYNModel : PageModel
 {
        public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Dictionary { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            var entityList = new List<Entity>();

            entityList.Add(new Entity() { Category = "Fr", Key = "Yes", Value = "Oui" });
            entityList.Add(new Entity() { Category = "Fr", Key = "No", Value = "Non" });
            entityList.Add(new Entity() { Category = "Fr", Key = "One", Value = "Une" });

            entityList.Add(new Entity() { Category = "En", Key = "Yes", Value = "yes" });
            entityList.Add(new Entity() { Category = "En", Key = "No", Value = "no" });
            entityList.Add(new Entity() { Category = "En", Key = "One", Value = "one" });


            Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
            Dictionary = entityList
                       .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
                       .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>>(x.Key, x.ToList().ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Value)))
                       .ToList().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

        }
}
```

So in the javascript part I could parse the dictionary:

```
 var dictionary = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.Dictionary))');
```

And the result is like this:

```
{"Fr":{"Yes":"Oui","No":"Non","One":"Une"},"En":{"Yes":"yes","No":"no","One":"one"}}
```

Now I could access my object by Searching via name:

```
var yesValue = dictionary["Fr"]["Yes"];
```

But the objective is to create kind of dynamic javascript object to access it like this:

```
dictionary.Fr.Yes
```

How could I create dynamic objects in javascript to access the value like this? any idea?

**UPDATE**:

As  [Mateusz Kleinert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3525449/mateusz-kleinert) said, It is already available with same object: [Property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

So there is not a question any more .

Comment: Is there an actual requirement that you need dot notation on these objects or is it just a _preference_?

Comment: @Drewness  It is just a preference.

Comment: You can access your `dictionary` object like that. I guess I'm confused on the issue.

Comment: Your `dictionary` object should allow a dot notation as long as the property you want to access is a valid JavaScript identifier - see [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Comment: @MateuszKleinert Oh, Thank you, It is already work. :)